# Change default directory for website in Amazon EC2 Linux instance

Tags: zend-framework, amazon-ec2

I want to be able to install a Zend - based site on Amazon EC2 Linux instance. To be able to do that, I need to have the main directory name as "public" rather than "html" as is default for EC2.

How can I change the path to the site's default directory from /var/www/html/ to /var/www/public/ ?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I'd quite like to work this out as well - I had a poke around in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` but it didn't seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Oliver is on the right track. You need to do 2 things:

1. Update the `DocumentRoot` statement within the `httpd.conf` file to your new home directory.
2. Restart your web service for the change to take effect.

So for example, do the following command:

```
sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Then look for the following line by typing `/DocumentRoot` + ENTER in the vi editor:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
```

Now just change the document root directory to whatever you want.(In the vi editor, move the cursor where you want it, press `i` to switch to insert mode, modify the code, then press `ESC` to get out of insert mode.) You can (and probably should) also change any `<Directory` statements that immediately follow, as these relax some access standards and shouldn't apply at a level above your web root. For example, you may see this:

```
#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
```

I recommend changing this to:

```
#
# Relax access to content within /var/www/html/drupal.
#
<Directory "/var/www/html/drupal">
```

Changing the comment is purely for consistency should anyone else review your code later. There are probably at least 2 statements that fit this pattern in the file, so look for and change them.

Save your changes when finished by typing `:x` and pressing `ENTER`.

Finally, a crucial step: restart your web service! This is a commonly overlooked step. The command will vary based on your server setup, but will probably be very close to:

`sudo service mysqld restart`

Check your website when finished to make sure it's going to the right default folder when you just use the domain name with no additional folders. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry... I'm a Drupal developer and used my example for a typical Drupal website setup. Should have put 'var/www/public` instead of `var/www/html/drupal' in my example.