# Public url issue in aws in laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have hosted my site on aws through ftp,

now when i access this

> url :  http://X.XXX.XXX.X/projectfoldername/

[image]

i can access the page after i use

> http://X.XXX.XXX.X/projectfoldername/public

but i want to remove public changed htaccess file also but when i upload it on cpanel it is working.

> .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all Linux OS's have a .conf file that you can use to tell it which folder is the public folder. This needs to be updated for Laravel to work.

From here (https://bobcares.com/blog/cpanel-change-root-directory/), for cPanel:
4. Updating cPanel files
cPanel/WHM does not have an option to change the document root of the main domain via any interface. By default it is the public_html folder in the user home directory.

In certain rare scenarios, we have customers who want their document root to be changed to another folder than public_html.

This has to be done from the backend by updating the cPanel user account file at /var/cpanel/userdata/username/domainname .

The following parameters are updated with the desired directories.

```
documentroot: /home/steinknu/public_html 

 scriptalias: 
   - 
     path: /home/steinknu/public_html/cgi-bin/
```

For sites with SSL installed, the configuration file for SSL is also updated accordingly.

This file is available at the location /var/cpanel/userdata/username/domain_SSL .

After making the changes, the user data cache is updated and Apache configuration file is rebuilt to reflect the changes in the corresponding files.

The Apache and PHP-FPM services are restarted and we verify the relevant configuration files to ensure that they are all updated properly.

Comment: Thanks but i'm using aws, in which file i have to change ?

Comment: Oh, are you using the AWS Linux? Or did you choose a different AMI? Personally I use the Bitnami LAMP AMI now, and it's pretty easy to work with. Do you know which OS is on it? Kind of sounds like AWS Linux

Comment: It is using ubuntu

Comment: Hm. You can follow these steps to locate the DocumentRoot via CLI
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894892/change-default-directory-for-website-in-amazon-ec2-linux-instance/45257176

Comment: Can i run these commands if i have ftp access

Comment: If you don't have SSH access, then no. If your FTP is using a key to log in, then probably you could with PuTTY.

Comment: Here is a link that outlines Ubuntu 18's process. If you only have FTP access, you may be able to back out of the public directory and see a conf file, depends on their settings.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-an-apache-web-root-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-18-04